# How to remove specific param from url?

Tags: angular

I have this route :

```
www.test.com/evidention?procesId=12&esid=12
```

I want to remove only this esid. Any suggestion how can i do that?

Comment: $location.search('myQueryStringParameter', null);  this might help

Comment: How does it get there the first place? Can you provide us some supporting code? It might only be me but I am unsure what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: I have search form and i added that as param for what i search for, but at the end i want to remove it because when i reloaded page i want to have url without that param, because there is some logic based on that param. I'm adding it with router.navigate

Comment: @Ali how can i include this $location.search ? i tried from Location angular/common but its not working

Comment: @None which angular version are you using?

Comment: 4.2.6 im using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the component or service where you want this deletion you can do the following:

```ts
export class ComponentOrService
{
    constructor(
      protected readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
      protected readonly router: Router
    ) { }

    deleteQueryParameterFromCurrentRoute()
    {
        const params = { ...this.route.snapshot.queryParams };
        delete params.esid;
        this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: params });
    }
}
```

PS: `[]` here means to stay on the same route and only change `queryParams`

Comment: For anyone wondering why the spread for the params const - because otherwise the params will become a reference and you will not be able to delete/change the query parameters with it.

Answer (score 2):

In angular 7+ there is error with "no provider for activatedroutesnapshot"

insteated you can use from ActivatedRoute

in constructor use

```
    private _ActivatedRoute: ActivatedRoute
```

and with this you can change url parameters

```
    var snapshot = this._ActivatedRoute.snapshot;
    const params = { ...snapshot.queryParams };
    delete params.esid
    this.router.navigate([], { queryParams: params });
```